# How to check for read and unread items in uitableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a uitableview which displays monthly newsletters from parse database. How can I check for unread newsletters and show them in red color to users? Also I want to badge the table view cell. I'm new to ios programming I checked a lot of posts but nothing seems to be clear. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution for read and unread items :

Add one column in parse database with name like  `msgread` and `type of data` be `boolean` which is by `default value with 0 means unread and 1 means read`so when displaying items in UITableViewCell you can know its read or unread.

Whenever `user clicks tableview cell` then make `background call` for that item to `change msgread to 1`.

## Solution for badge the table view cell :

Use custom tableView cell like [TDBadgedCell](https://github.com/tmdvs/TDBadgedCell) for your requirement.

[image]

Comment: Sorry to bother you i'm new to parse. By add a variable do you mean add a column "msgread" to parse database?

Comment: Yes add one column is what i meant